# Java:concept about object

Tags: java, object

```
    public class ex11_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Object a=new Person("abc1","def1","ghi1");
        System.out.println(a.toString());
        Object b=new Person("abc2","def2","ghi2");

        System.out.println(a.toString());
    }
}

class Person{
    private static String name;
    private static String address;
    private static String phoneNo;

    public Person(){
    }

    public Person(String name,String address,String phoneNo){
        setName(name);
        setAddress(address);
        setPhoneNo(phoneNo);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return super.toString()+(" "+getName()+","+getAddress()+","+getPhoneNo()+".");
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return Person.name;
    }

    public static void setName(String name) {
        Person.name = name;
    }

    public static String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public static void setAddress(String address) {
        Person.address = address;
    }

    public static String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }

    public static void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        Person.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }
}
```

Hi everybody.I am a beginner of Java programming and would like to ask the question on OOP. In this small program, I create a class of Person and test its toString() method.

The result of the test is:

```
Person@635b9e68 abc1,def1,ghi1.
Person@635b9e68 abc2,def2,ghi2.
```

I am wondering why the data field of b will replace that of a after the creation of b.
Thanks

Comment: Remove the static keyword from your `Person` class variables. The way you have them now effectively defines 'global' state - aka, they share the same value across ***all*** instances of your class.

Comment: Problem solved.
But how to create another class, say named as Student with data field String status, using the keyword super in the constructor?

Comment: The [Oracle Trail on Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) has nice documentation on subclassing (see the Bicycle/Mountain Bike example).

Answer (score 5):

Your member variables are static and are not attached to any instance of the class.

```
private static String name;
private static String address;
private static String phoneNo;
```

Static members will be available across instances of the class. To correct it, change them to non-static member variables.

```
private String name;
private String address;
private String phoneNo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `name`, `address` and `phoneNo` fields are declared as static, there is only one copy for all objects of the class `Person`, or these variables are shared among all objects of this class.

You should understand the difference between `static` and `instance` variables here. Check these links for more info: [link1](http://www.coderanch.com/t/528608/java/java/Difference-Static-Instance-variable), [link2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0):

Because you've declared your class variables as `static`

```
private static String name;
private static String address;
private static String phoneNo;
```

This means that every instance of `Person` will have exactly the same values

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are using `static` variable of class, which are like the global variable to all instance (object) of that class. Therefore, if you are modifying the static variable inside the instance(non-static) method, their modification is reflect as global .

Learn more about variables in Java at [this link](http://anotherjavaduke.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/different-types-of-variables-in-java/)